# json parsing and displaying the values to a list using a singleton class

Tags: android, json

```
package com.pack.indium.mismobile.activities;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class SummaryFoFinalReport extends Activity {
    private Upload_Download_Json interaction;
    private SharedPreferences defpreferences;
    private String PREFS_NAME = "order";
    Integer firstName;
    String from_date, to_date;
    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray details = null;
    JSONArray company = null;
    ProgressBar progress_bar;
    ListView list;
    ReportFoFinalSmry1 smry1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // getting the values from FoFinalBillFragment class
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        firstName = intent.getIntExtra("firstName", 1);
        from_date = intent.getStringExtra("fromDate");
        to_date = intent.getStringExtra("toDate");
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#188BC0")));
        interaction = new Upload_Download_Json();
        defpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        setContentView(R.layout.rpt_fo_finalbill_rpt_smry);
        progress_bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        new FetchTask().execute();
    }

    // all fetchtask
    class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        Integer firstName;
        String from_date, to_date;
        Upload_Download_Json interaction;
        ProgressDialog progress;

        public FetchTask() {
            interaction = new Upload_Download_Json();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progress_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            String json = interaction.sendJsonPost(getJsonString(), "http://"
                    + defpreferences.getString("defaultip", "ww")
                    + "/onlineMisservice.asmx/FinalBillDetails");

            return json;

        }

        private String getJsonString() {
            JSONObject authentic = new JSONObject();
            try {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                firstName = intent.getIntExtra("firstName", 1);
                from_date = intent.getStringExtra("fromDate");
                to_date = intent.getStringExtra("toDate");

                authentic.put("FromDate", from_date);
                authentic.put("ToDate", to_date);
                authentic.put("ReqType", firstName);
                authentic.put("Level", 1);

            } catch (JSONException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }

            return authentic.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (progress_bar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                progress_bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            JSONObject obj;
            try {
                obj = new JSONObject(result);
                details = obj.getJSONArray("ReportDtls");
                for (int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(i);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }
}
```

in this class i need to implement a list view which has an onclick listener which triggers an activity. And in the onpostexecute method(in asynctask) how can i use a singleton class which helps me in parsing the incoming json, these incoming values are the one i have to populate in the list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_date_border" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/list_header_margin"
                    android:text="Srl" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/list_header_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:text="Month" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/list_header_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:text="Fin Year" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/rpt_fo_finalbill_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </ListView>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my xml with the list view (rpt_fo_finalbill_rpt_smry.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/finalbillsmry_srl"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/finalbillsmry_month"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/finalbillsmry_finyear"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the list item i need to populate in the list view (list_item.xml)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be a homework. Anyway, you create "your singleton class" and invoke its helper methods in order to parse json and take required actions.

Answer (score 0):

Create A singleton class  [Check this tutorial](http://javaforbegineer.blogspot.in/2016/01/android-display-json-response-in.html)
AppController.java

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }


    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this for your MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    JSONArray contact = null;
    private String urlJsonObj = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";
    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    //private String jsonResponse;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
    ListView lv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        makeJsonObjectRequest();


    }

    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
        pDialog.show();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                //jsonResponse = "";
                try {
                    contact = response.getJSONArray("contacts");
                    //jsonResponse += "Contacts :        " + "\n\n";

                    for (int i = 0; i < contact.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject details = (JSONObject) contact.get(i);
                        //String id = details.getString("id");
                        String name = details.getString("name");
                        String email = details.getString("email");
                        //String address = details.getString("address");
                        //String gender = details.getString("gender");
                        JSONObject phone = details.getJSONObject("phone");
                        String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                       // String home = phone.getString("home");
                        //String office = phone.getString("office");


                       /* jsonResponse += "Id: " + id + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Address: " + address + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Gender: " + gender + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Office: " + office + "\n\n\n\n\n";*/
                        HashMap<String, String> contct = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        contct.put("name", name);
                        contct.put("email", email);
                        contct.put("mobile", mobile);
                        contactList.add(contct);
                        //adapter to set response in textview
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email", "mobile"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                                R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


                    }


                    //txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                hidepDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // hide the progress dialog
                hidepDialog();


            }


        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

    }


    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

[See Here Full Tutorial](http://javaforbegineer.blogspot.in/2016/01/android-display-json-response-in.html)